# Mypy doesn't catch type mysmatch

Tags: python, mypy

**mypy==0.720**

My file:

```
import yaml


def read_secret_yaml() -> str: # Real return type is dict.
    """
    Read secret.yaml (not added to Git).
    """
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(current_dir, "../../doc/secret.yaml")
    stream = open(path, "r")
    secret = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

    return secret
```

This function returns a dict. I intentionally changed the result tytpe to str to check whether mypy catches this type mysmatch.

The command was:

```
mypy --strict-optional general_lib.py
```

I received no error message.

Could you tell me whether this is a correct behavior of mypy or I have done something wrong.

Comment: Is there a type hint for `yaml.load`? If not, `mypy` will assume you know what you are doing and pretend that `yaml.load` returns a `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `yaml.load` will return a value of type `Any`. This is intentional: a YAML file could contain any number of things (a dict, a list...), so there's going to be no way for a type checker to deduce what exactly your `secret` variable is going to be.

To put it another way, this is a case where your data is legitimately dynamic, which means there's really no good static type you can use.

---

If you want mypy to warn you when you try returning something of type `Any` from a function that doesn't *say* it's going to return `Any`, use the `--warn-return-any` flag. This would have caused mypy to report a `Returning Any from function declared to return "str"` error.

You can also explore using the [disallow dynamic typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#disallow-dynamic-typing) family of mypy flags if you want to get even more strict about this.